# how to do clustering or classification for multiple string feratures data in python machine learning

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I want to do clustering data which has multiple categorical featueres.
the data consists of :
{
"fieldA": "valueA",
"fieldB": "valueB",
"fieldC": "valueC",
"fieldD": "valueD",
"fieldE": "valueE",
"fieldF": "valueF",
"fieldG": "valueG",
}

usually, the human can cluster the data manually(some fields in each data can be different, but human can cluster same data by whose knowledge.), but I want to implement automatic system.

I've tried to apply some ML algorithms of clusterung for categorical features (like KModes), but it's not clear.

could you please help ?
have a good day, thank you

Comment: what you want to cluster, your question is very unclear.

Comment: @PrakashDahal oh sorry. clustering same data is what I want.

Comment: Do you want to cluster dictionary? Can you give real data examples?

Comment: don't care any data format. but data consists of dictionary now. I don't have real data now this is because security issues :(

Comment: Dictionary data is already supposed to clustered based on keys